# Poner html en un div con jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Existe algo en jQuery para realizar lo siguiente?

```
document.getElementById('ejemplo').innerHTML+= '<div> HTML de ejemplo </div>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `append()`

```
$("#ejemplo").append("<div> HTML de ejemplo </div>");
```